Adding a column to summarize week
I want to add a "Week" column to my dataset. This week column runs from week 1 - week 5. I want to add this to a long data set (12) rows.
Is there a way I can code to make this function reoccurring to the entire data set to it looks like:



ID
Week
Distance




Name 1
Week 1
1000


Name 1
Week 2
1500


Name 1
Week 3
1100


Name 1
Week 4
900


Name 1
Week 5
1400


Name 2
Week 1
1300


Name 2
Week 2
1050


Name 2
Week 3
1500


Name 2
Week 4
1190


Name 2
Week 5
950


Name 3
Week 1
1350


Name 3
Week 2
1200



I have tried doing:
df %>% mutate(week = c(1:5))

However, I come up with this error:
week must be size 12 or 1, not 5.

If your input is what you show but without the week column, then df |> mutate(week = paste("Week", row_number()), .by = ID)

c(1:5) is equivalent to c(1,2,3,4,5). Basically the error message is telling you that you are trying to add a new column of length 5 to a dataframe with 12 rows. Something like this should work:
mutate(df, week = rep(c(1:5), length.out = nrow(df)))

By wrapping the vector c(1:5) in rep we repeat it until we get a vector of length specified in the length.out argument which we can set to the nrow(df) which is the number of rows in the dataframe.

If you just need to repeat "Week 1" to "Week 5" until the data frame runs out, you could use sapply to a seq representing the row numbers:
Sample data frame:
df=data.frame(ID=c(rep('Name 1',5), rep('Name 2',5), rep('Name 3', 2)),
              distance=rnorm(12))

The following function just repeats the numbers 1-5 via a mod operation on the row numbers
sapply(1:dim(df)[1], FUN=function(x) ((x-1) %% 5)+1)

Thus
paste0("Week ",sapply(1:dim(df)[1], FUN=function(x) ((x-1) %% 5)+1))

produces the column you are after.
NB: This method will not work if the rows are not sorted and/or there are varying numbers of weeks per ID.

Using rep_len.
> transform(d, week=rep_len(1:5, nrow(d)))
       ID Distance week
1  Name 1     1000    1
2  Name 1     1500    2
3  Name 1     1100    3
4  Name 1      900    4
5  Name 1     1400    5
6  Name 2     1300    1
7  Name 2     1050    2
8  Name 2     1500    3
9  Name 2     1190    4
10 Name 2      950    5
11 Name 3     1350    1
12 Name 3     1200    2

or
> transform(d, week=paste('Week', rep_len(1:5, nrow(d))))
       ID Distance   week
1  Name 1     1000 Week 1
2  Name 1     1500 Week 2
3  Name 1     1100 Week 3
4  Name 1      900 Week 4
5  Name 1     1400 Week 5
6  Name 2     1300 Week 1
7  Name 2     1050 Week 2
8  Name 2     1500 Week 3
9  Name 2     1190 Week 4
10 Name 2      950 Week 5
11 Name 3     1350 Week 1
12 Name 3     1200 Week 2

Note, that we can recycle if n %% nrow(d) == 0.
> t(nrow(d) %% 1:12 == 0)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]  [,5] [,6]  [,7]  [,8]  [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12]
[1,] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE

E.g. n == 6:
> transform(d, week=1:6)
       ID Distance week
1  Name 1     1000    1
2  Name 1     1500    2
3  Name 1     1100    3
4  Name 1      900    4
5  Name 1     1400    5
6  Name 2     1300    6
7  Name 2     1050    1
8  Name 2     1500    2
9  Name 2     1190    3
10 Name 2      950    4
11 Name 3     1350    5
12 Name 3     1200    6


*Data:*

> dput(d)
structure(list(ID = c("Name 1", "Name 1", "Name 1", "Name 1", 
"Name 1", "Name 2", "Name 2", "Name 2", "Name 2", "Name 2", "Name 3", 
"Name 3"), Distance = c(1000L, 1500L, 1100L, 900L, 1400L, 1300L, 
1050L, 1500L, 1190L, 950L, 1350L, 1200L), week = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L)), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = "data.frame")

